# Como posso criar um array em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Olá
Começei recentemente a usar esta plataforma para tentar esclarecer algumas dúvidas e estou a ter algumas dificuldades em criar arrays para armazenar dados através de Javascript.

Penso que o erro seja algo simples no entanto não consigo determinar o que é.

```html
 carros = ["Fiat", "Ferrari", "Toyota"];
```

agradeço toda a ajuda desde já que for fornecida.

Comment: Se o problema era criar um array, parabéns ,vc já criou. Só dar um console.log(carros) que verá o array. Pode dar um **carros.length** par ver o tamanho do array entre outras muitas coisas que podem ser feitas.

Comment: Qual é exatamente a sua questão ? Você colocou o código javascript no snippet como html, e por isso o código aparece escrito na tela, pois normalmente nada iria aparecer. Criar um array não implica mostrar nada em lado algum.

Comment: Esse array que você colocou pode ser acessado assim: ```carros[0]``` (irá retornar o primeiro índice do array), e assim por diante. Você acessa os elementos do array usando colchetes, com o primeiro índice sendo o 0 (zero).

Comment: Não me soube explicar muito bem mas o usuário @DavidMv já me conseguiu ajudar neste caso. Porém agradeço as informações dadas para futuras perguntas nesta plataforma :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá
Caso queiras armazenar em diferentes variáveis podes utilizar esta função:

```js
var carro1 = "Fiat";
var carro2 = "Ferrari";
var carro3 = "Toyota";
```

caso queiras por tudo dentro da mesma variável podes fazer desta forma:

```js
var carros = ["Fiat", "Ferrari", "Toyota"];
```

ou desta:

```js
var carros = [
        "Fiat", 
        "Ferrari", 
        "Toyota"
        ];
```

Podes usar para te ajudar com a programação este site: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/default.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Você apenas esqueceu de por o var, no inicio, Exemplo.:

```
var carros = ["Parati", "Ferrari", "BMW"]
```

Você também pode usar o let

```
let carros = ["Parati", "Ferrari", "BMW"]
```